# SpeechSynthesizer.AddLexicon is not respecting the custom overrides

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, lexicon

I am using speech synthesizer for converting text to speech. I wanted to use a custom lexicon file so I used the AddLexicon  method as recommended on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.addlexicon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Here is my function

```
     public void ReadOut(string sentence)
    {
        using (SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
        {
            synth.SelectVoiceByHints(gender: VoiceGender.Male, age: VoiceAge.Adult, voiceAlternate: 1, culture: CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
            synth.Rate = -2;
            var fqn = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            var uri = new Uri("file://" + fqn + "/CustomLexicon.pls");
            synth.AddLexicon(uri, "application/pls+xml");
            synth.Speak(sentence);
        }

    }
```

and my lexicon file is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <lexicon version="1.0" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/01/pronunciation-lexicon"
  alphabet="x-microsoft-ups" xml:lang="en-US">
 <lexeme>
     <grapheme> BLUE </grapheme>
     <phoneme> B L I P </phoneme>
   </lexeme>
</lexicon>
```

However, when i pass "BLUE" to the function it still outputs BLUE instead of BLIP. Am I missing something?

Note : I made sure that the pls file exists in the right location and its contents are correctly populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the System.Speech implementation of the synthesizer, as per the accepted answer here: [How do I use a lexicon with SpeechSynthesizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529164/how-do-i-use-a-lexicon-with-speechsynthesizer)